Python library: optionally support numpy types without depending on numpy
Context
We develop a Python library that contains a function expecting a numlike parameter. We specify this in our signature and make use of python type hints:
def cool(value: float | int | List[float | int]) 

 Problem & Goal
During runtime, we noticed it's fine to pass in numpy number types as well, e.g. np.float16(1.2345). So we thought: why not incorporate "numpy number types" into our signature as this would be beneficial for the community that will use our library.
However, we don't want numpy as dependency in our project. We'd like to only signify in the method signature that we can take a float, int, a list of them OR any "numpy number type". If the user hasn't installed numpy on their system, they should still be able to use our library and just ignore that they could possibly pass in a "numpy number type" as well.
We don't want to depend on numpy as we don't use it in our library (except for allowing their types in our method signature). So why include it in our dependency graph? There's no reason to do so. One dependency less is better.
Additional requirements/context

We search for an answer that is compatible with all Python versions >=3.8.
(The answer should work with setuptools>=69.0.)
The answer should be such that we get proper IntelliSense (Ctrl + Space) when typing cool( in an IDE, e.g. VSCode.
This is what our pyproject.toml looks like.

Efforts

We've noticed the option [project.optional-dependencies] for the pyproject.toml file, see here. However, it remains unclear how this optional dependencies declaration helps us in providing optional numpy datatypes in our method signatures.
numpy provides the numpy.typing type annotations. Is it somehow possible to only depend on this subpackage?
We did search on search engines and found this SO question, however our question is more specific with regards to how we can only use types from another module. We also found this SO question, but despite having "optional" in its title, it's not about optional numpy types.


Could you only conditionally import numpy when running type checking? In other words, could you use the if TYPE_CHECKING: trick for avoiding circular imports described in this video?

Practical question though: why don't you want to include numpy? Sure, it's "big" but it's only big for a Python package. In absolute terms, it's basically irrelevantly small in terms of a download and footprint on the filesystem.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Sure, it might be small in terms of size. Yet, it's still a dependency which we, as maintainers of a library, have to take care of, e.g. update it's version. We don't have any line of code that makes use of numpy, so why should installation of our library include a step where numpy is installed on the users machine?

Defer evaluation of annotations, and only import numpy conditionally.
from __future__ import annotations
import typing as t

if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    import numpy as np

def cool(value: int | np.floating | etc ...):
    ...

Now the numpy dependency is only necessary when type-checking.
See PEP 563 – Postponed Evaluation of Annotations
Side-questions..

numpy provides the numpy.typing type annotations. Is it somehow possible to only depend on this subpackage?

No, this is not possible.

We've noticed the option [project.optional-dependencies] for the pyproject.toml file ...

It doesn't really help you much here. It could still be useful if you wanted "extra" dependencies which the user can opt-in for, e.g.:
pip install mypkg          # install with required dependencies
pip install mypkg[typing]  # install with extra dependencies such as numpy

Then you could use this to easily install the package along with the soft-deps in your CI, for example.

Using numbers.Number picks up stuff like decimal.Decimal and fractions.Fraction, though. (It also picks up complex - you'd need numbers.Real to exclude that.)

decimal.Decimal is unlikely to be fine. Even just trying to add 0.5 to a decimal.Decimal produces a TypeError. This will also be a problem at type-checking time. There is very little you can do with a numbers.Number instance without knowing a more specific type.

Unfortunately, for option 1, pyright (and therefore also the Pylance language server in VSCode) gives this error: error: Argument of type "float16" cannot be assigned to parameter "param" of type "Real" in function "blablah". "float16" is incompatible with "Real" (reportArgumentType)

Note that I've just written down this question in the pyright repo here.

I've got an answer here and your option 1 is not giving correct IntelliSense due to that issue. However, option 2 is working, yeah ;) People might find np.floating | np.integer useful to allow any numpy number types.

Hmm, interesting. Might be @MartijnPieters knows something more than me here because he has used numbers.Number when adding types to an open source project of mine recently, and the CI uses pyright. Seems pretty half-baked if stdlib abstract base classes don't work at all with type checkers?!

@Splines What about using the protocol typing.SupportsFloat, does that work?

After reading Guido's comments in mypy #3186 Option 1 has been removed from this answer (visitors - check the edit history if you want to see it). Kind of a bummer, because Option 2 is pretty ugly imo.

@wim Would you mind providing an exact link you're referring to since the mypy issue page is very long?

It's more or less this comment which made me realize option 1 is not workable.  int, float etc don't actually inherit from numbers types, those are virtual subclasses and isinstance checks are handled dynamically at runtime. Virtual subclass relationships can not be discerned by static type checkers, and there are no plans to support that in mypy or pyright, nor to override it in typeshed. So the numeric tower numbers ABCs are only useful for runtime type checkers, not for type checkers which use static analysis.
